# Need help parsing html to python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, finance

Trying to extract data from html into a dataframe

[Table Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOujG.png)

from this piece of html

```html
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td><table width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="news-table" class="fullview-news-outer">
<tr><td width="130" align="right" style="white-space:nowrap">Apr-22-20 01:30AM&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td align="left"><a href="https://finance.yahoo.com/news/stmicro-sees-declining-demand-automotive-053033014.html" target="_blank" class="tab-link-news">STMicro Sees Declining Demand for Automotive Chips Next Quarter</a> <span style="color:#aa6dc0;font-size:9px">Bloomberg</span></td></tr>
<tr><td width="130" align="right" style="white-space:nowrap">Apr-21-20 10:43PM&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td align="left"><a href="https://www.investors.com/market-trend/stock-market-today/dow-jones-futures-crude-oil-prices-test-coronavirus-stock-market-rally-netflix-snap-chipotle-earnings/?src=A00220" target="_blank" class="tab-link-news">Dow Jones Futures: Crashing Crude Oil Prices Test Coronavirus Stock Market Rally; 5 Big Earnings Movers</a> <span style="color:#aa6dc0;font-size:9px">Investor's Business Daily</span></td></tr>
<tr><td width="130" align="right">09:31PM&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td align="left"><a href="https://finance.yahoo.com/news/facebook-plow-5-7-billion-005209259.html" target="_blank" class="tab-link-news">Facebook to Invest $5.7 Billion in Ambanis Jio Platforms</a> <span style="color:#aa6dc0;font-size:9px">Bloomberg</span></td></tr>
<tr><td width="130" align="right">08:00PM&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td align="left"><a href="https://finance.yahoo.com/news/plastic-bags-making-comeback-last-000001077.html" target="_blank" class="tab-link-news">Plastic Bags Are Making a Comeback. Will It Last?</a> <span style="color:#aa6dc0;font-size:9px">Bloomberg</span></td></tr>
<tr><td width="130" align="right">07:27PM&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td align="left"><a href="https://finance.yahoo.com/news/rpt-bluetooth-phone-apps-tracking-232727649.html" target="_blank" class="tab-link-news">RPT-Bluetooth phone apps for tracking COVID-19 show modest early results</a> <span style="color:#aa6dc0;font-size:9px">Reuters</span></td></tr>
<tr><td width="130" align="right" style="white-space:nowrap">Apr-20-20 09:00PM&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td align="left"><a href="https://finance.yahoo.com/news/jerremy-newsome-shares-rules-options-010014004.html" target="_blank" class="tab-link-news">Jerremy Newsome Shares The Rules For His Options Strategy</a> <span style="color:#aa6dc0;font-size:9px">Benzinga</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Apr-22-20 01:30AM  STMicro Sees Declining Demand for Automotive Chips Next Quarter Bloomberg
Apr-21-20 10:43PM  Dow Jones Futures: Crashing Crude Oil Prices Test Coronavirus Stock Market Rally; 5 Big Earnings Movers Investor's Business Daily
09:31PM  Facebook to Invest $5.7 Billion in Ambanis Jio Platforms Bloomberg
08:00PM  Plastic Bags Are Making a Comeback. Will It Last? Bloomberg
07:27PM  RPT-Bluetooth phone apps for tracking COVID-19 show modest early results Reuters
Apr-20-20 09:00PM  Jerremy Newsome Shares The Rules For His Options Strategy Benzinga

'''

Comment: If you want to get only the symbols that you can see in HTML page, count open and closing tags (< and >) If the balance is zero, keep the part.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does not work?

Answer (score 0):

I Finally figured out how to parse this data here is a working solution I still have a date problem but it puts data in a dataframe

```
ticker = 'AAPL'
NEWS_URL = 'https://finviz.com/news.ashx'
STOCK_URL = 'https://finviz.com/quote.ashx'
page_parsed, _ = http_request_get(url=STOCK_URL, payload={'t': ticker}, parse=True)
table = page_parsed.cssselect('table[class="fullview-news-outer"]')[0]
all_news = page_parsed.cssselect('a[class="tab-link-news"]')
headers = ['Datetime', 'Description', 'Space', 'Source']
urls = [row.get('href') for row in all_news] 
data = [dict(zip(headers, row.xpath('td//text()'))) for row in table[0:]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(urls) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data) 
mergedDf = df2.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True)
mergedDf = mergedDf.rename(columns={0: "url"})
mergedDf = mergedDf.drop(['Space'], axis=1)
mergedDf['ticker'] = ticker
```